# Adding a Batch/Powershell file to a compilation (Build) C# Powershell

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, shell, batch-file, powershell

I'm working on a c# project where i'm trying to run powershell scripts, output them to a CSV and read the CSV and output it to a Checked list box.

I've added a powershell file as a resource with Build Action 'Compile' and Copy to output directory 'Do Not Copy'.

The basic content of the file is :

```
Get-CimInstance -Query "SELECT * from Win32_Service where name LIKE 'sql%'" | select Name, State , StartMode | convertto-csv > proctest.csv
```

i try to access this file using this string

```
string ps_path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\GetSvc.ps1";
```

The PS code i use is

```
RunspaceConfiguration runspaceconfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceconfiguration);
runspace.Open();
RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
Command mycommand = new Command(ps_path);
pipeline.Commands.Add(mycommand);
pipeline.Invoke();
runspace.Close();
```

This works fine during compilation but when i build an exe and try to run it, i get an error saying the GetSvc.ps1 file is not found.

How do i make the file a part of the build ?!

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you should read up on Embedded Resources. You could look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319292 for example.

Answer (score 1):

Make the build action for the script be `Embedded Resource`.  Then take a look at [lines 149-155](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=5A8D2641E0963A97&id=5A8D2641E0963A97%217521) on how to extract the script inside the C# exe.  In this example, I had zipped the script to compact it. If you skip that step then you can remove line 152 and in line 153 use stream instead of gZipStream.

Comment: get a value cannot be null for var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);  The script is set to build as an embedded resource and has just a single line in it.. not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: That sounds like stream is null so this line is likely failing `using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Resources.Script.ps1.gz"))`.  Not to suprising as getting the `name` of the resource is often the trickiest part as that uses namespace name as well IIRC.  Open up your compiled assembly in dotPeek or Reflector and see what the resource name actually is and use that name.